# MySQL Crashing on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, crash

For the past 4 days MySQL keeps crashing on running scripts, like once / day

this is the error log

```
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=39
max_threads=100
threads_connected=34
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 336508 K
bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

thd: 0x92025f38
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x95dce36c thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2d) [0x6b65ad]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_segfault+0x494) [0x3823d4]
[0x110400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(MYSQLparse(void*)+0x6aa) [0x3b42da]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, char const*, unsigned int, char const**)+0x23e) [0x39ce6e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(enum_server_command, THD*, char*, unsigned int)+0xf35) [0x39df25]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0xf3) [0x39f0e3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x2a0) [0x38dbd0]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0(+0x596e) [0x93d96e]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0xd78a4e]
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort...
thd->query at 0x86982ef4 is an invalid pointer
thd->thread_id=2906
thd->killed=NOT_KILLED
```

The box runs on 2GB RAM, by my calculations it shouldn't have the problem with max memory. I've specifically lowered the memory requirements to a minimum but still getting the errors.

```
mysql> show variables like "sort_buffer%";
+------------------+---------+
| Variable_name    | Value   |
+------------------+---------+
| sort_buffer_size | 1048576 |
+------------------+---------+
```

It crashed today on this SQL query

```
ALTER TABLE FieldDefaultValue MODIFY value_field varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 collate utf8_bin;
```

Anyone got any similar experience ?

EDIT:

The table in question actually doesn't contain much data, the database has much larger tables:

```
mysql> desc fielddefaultvalue;
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fielddefaultvalue_Id | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version              | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value_field          | varchar(2000) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| optimistic_version   | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| property_fk          | bigint(20)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| esg_fk               | bigint(20)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from fielddefaultvalue;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      690 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It also fails on multiple inserts (400-500) of little data, but not all the time, the same script can run properly once or crash it

EDIT 2: After crash recovery the error log also reports:

```
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 9433498.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

my.cnf

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
key_buffer              = 16M
key_buffer_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 100
table_cache            = 512
thread_concurrency     = 4
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
open_files_limit = 65536
default_character_set=utf8

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 64M

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 250M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
```

EDIT: 5 hours later

It just crashed again on the same "regular" script, it's a 25.000 line update script on a date column.

Same error message:

```
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 186 4056481576
110620 17:30:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Read
```

Funny thing is, I've ran this script today and didn't fail, but it did now.

Comment: Which version and is it innoDB or MyISAM tables?

Comment: Are you running MySQL Cluster or just MySQL Server?

Comment: It's innodb database with a simple MySQL Server.
Need to mention that this is mostly a testing enviroment for devs, it has no problems on importing large SQL dumps (400 MB or larger ) but crashes on SQL's that do multiple inserts or alter tables with multiple rows

Comment: key_buffer and key_buffer_size are the same setting, so setting them both is redundant. Especially to different values.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is running out of address space; please post your entire my.cnf.

Running 32-bit OS in production is not a good idea.

However, what you should do is:

1. Reproduce the fault on the same MySQL version on a non-production machine
2. Check that you are using a properly supported, current build from Oracle. If you are not, then install one of those and reproduce the problem. If you are running Redhat (or similar), then you can use Oracle's RPMs. They also provide some other distributions' packages and binaries in a tar.gz file. Your package vendor may patch MySQL with some dodgy patches. I never run OEM MySQL builds in production.
3. You seem to be running 32-bit. Ensure that you're not running out of address-space.

If you can reproduce the bug using a *standard* Oracle build on a *supported* operating system, you are not running out of memory / adress space and there is no hardware fault, then you can submit the bug to Oracle.

The best idea is to reproduce the test-case with the minimum amount of data / table size.

Comment: It's an ubuntu server box that our devs use (it's not a production environment but it is critical for the devs). We're using 5.1.41 since we haven't got to testing how 5.5 does with our software. It hasn't caused any problems for the past 3-4 months, since it's been installed, it's only been acting up for the past 4-5 days. No configuration has been changed in that time. I'm no expert in these matters, how can I check that it's not running out of address-space.

Comment: We have 5.1.41 running on various linux / windows boxes (production environments) and never caused any issues and definitely not this. I have thought of possibly being a faulty ram module, but I wanted to rule out a bad mysql config before addressing that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your innodb_log_file_size is not big enough - try with 256 MB in my.cnf:
  innodb_log_file_size=256M

You need to shut it down cleanly, remove the old logfiles, then restart - mysql will recreate new log files.

Answer (score 0):

Strange... I don't know how optimized the **ALTER TABLE** actually is on MySQL. Perhaps it consumes a lot of power. If the table contains a lot of data, try to move all your data into a temporary table and empty the main one. Then do your alter table and push the data back. If it has to do work on each row then you can split the work up like this and do a few records at a time.

Comment: The table actually doesn't contain a lot of data, compared to other tables

`code`