# InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 403. Cannot continue operation ; [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

i am facing the following error recently. Mysql was hosted by XAMPP in local, and recently getting repetitively Error.

```
2020-04-28  7:28:12 260 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2020-04-28  7:28:12 260 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 49152, but was only able to read 0
2020-04-28  7:28:12 260 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2020-04-28  7:28:12 260 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2020-04-28  7:28:12 260 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 403. Cannot continue operation
200428  7:28:17 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.16-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=11
max_threads=65537
thread_count=9
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 36501 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x2b34eecdd28
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!?ha_rnd_next@handler@@QEAAHPEAE@Z()
mysqld.exe!?rr_sequential@@YAHPEAUREAD_RECORD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?sub_select@@YA?AW4enum_nested_loop_state@@PEAVJOIN@@PEAUst_join_table@@_N@Z()
mysqld.exe!?disjoin@?$List@VItem@@@@QEAAXPEAV1@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?exec_inner@JOIN@@QEAAXXZ()
mysqld.exe!?exec@JOIN@@QEAAXXZ()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_select@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE_LIST@@IAEAV?$List@VItem@@@@PEAVItem@@IPEAUst_order@@434_KPEAVselect_result@@PEAVst_select_lex_unit@@PEAVst_select_lex@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?handle_select@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAULEX@@PEAVselect_result@@K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?execute_init_command@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAUst_mysql_lex_string@@PEAUst_mysql_rwlock@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEADIPEAVParser_state@@_N3@Z()
mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NW4enum_server_command@@PEAVTHD@@PEADI_N3@Z()
mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?pool_of_threads_scheduler@@YAXPEAUscheduler_functions@@PEAKPEAI@Z()
mysqld.exe!?tp_callback@@YAXPEAUTP_connection@@@Z()
ntdll.dll!TpReleaseWait()
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeResource()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x2b34ef77140): SELECT `JCY_PROGRAM_BOM_ID`, `JCY_PROGRAM_BOM_MATERIAL_ID`, `JCY_PROGRAM_BOM_PROGRAM_ID`, `JCY_PROGRAM_BOM_CREATED_BY`, `JCY_PROGRAM_BOM_CREATED_DATETIME` FROM `jcy_program_bom`

where jcy_program_bom_material_id = 45 AND JCY_PROGRAM_BOM_PROGRAM_ID = 18
Connection ID (thread ID): 260
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on
```

Once this happen, the XAMPP's MYSQL service will be forced stop. And i will have to restart it again.
Anyone know how to fix/encounter this issue? Any guide or comment will be much appreciate

Comment: I see no C++ code in your question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hi, updated.

Comment: Hope this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413577/3238940

Comment: @mightyteja thanks mate, i will definitely give it a try